# Integrals as Signed Measures (and vice Versa)?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

**1.** Can every integral (with respect to an integrable function) be written as a signed measure?

And does the function’s decomposition into positive and negative parts align somehow with the corresponding signed measure’s Jordan/Hahn decomposition into positive and negative measures?

**2.** Likewise, can every signed measure be written as the integral of some integrable function with respect to a measure (a la Radon-Nikodym)?

(Obviously this is trivially true for measures, just take the constant function $1$ as the integrand, but I want to know whether in general signed measures and integrals are in some sense equivalent concepts or not.)

**3.** Does some restriction to only functions of bounded variation somewhere come into play (even though we are considering arbitrary abstract measures)?

**4.** Would this lead to a quicker way of defining abstract Lebesgue(-Stieltjes) integrals?

---

I proved the first direction once, but I used the monotone and dominated convergence theorems, which seem to already require some notion of integration in order to be proved.

Perhaps there is a proof which does not a priori assume a notion of integral to be defined first. I.e. I would like to know if signed measures can really be shown to be the more fundamental object (and integrals as a convenient way of writing some subclass of them).

**UPDATE:** This problem is almost certainly related to the Jordan decomposition theorem for functions (which according to Wikipedia is something that exists). I will look into this further soon.